# How to determine the full size of a Panel (including scroll bars) in C#

Tags: .net, winforms, canvas, scroll, panel

The problem I am having is with a panel, which starts at the size 200x200 pixels. For the program I am writing, at any given time I need to know how big this panel is, but this gets difficult as AutoScroll is on and when large content is inserted the panel expands (and gets scroll bars).

I have looked a bit at AutoScrollPosition and AutoScrollOffset, and even tried implementing this in my solution - but it appears this only tells you information about the panel when the scroll bar is in a certain position - whereas at any given time I need to know the *total* size of the panel.

So basically, suppose some content got entered into the panel and taking the scrolling distance into account it really became a 600x750 pixel panel. Does anyone know of any way I can actually get this information?

Thanks

Comment: Is this WPF application?

Comment: My answer was based on the assumption that there is no property for this, but it turns out there is: PreferredSize.

Answer (score 4):

The "including scroll bars" clause makes the question unanswerable.  Because the scrollbars are only applied to the DisplayRectangle.

You can get the required size of the panel so that no scrollbars are necessary from the PreferredSize property.  You can get the height and width of the scrollbars from the SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight and VerticalScrollBarWidth properties.

Comment: +1 FWIW I think the "including scroll bars" just means "when scroll bars are showing".

Comment: Yep, PreferredSize is what the OP wants. @David: I tried your method - off by -1 pixel on each axis, oddly.

Comment: @Charles PreferredSize differed by 4 from my method when I tried. Go figure! But PreferredSize seems to be it. Must check that scroll bars are showing though.

Comment: @David: check the Padding of the Panel and the Margin of whatever you're putting in it. Those will both affect the results.

Comment: @David - Yes, Margin property which defaults to 3.  And you have to add the scrollbar's SmallChange property value which defaults to 1.  Scrollbars have been a massive pita as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 0):

When the contents of the Panel are bigger than its ClientSize, then AutoScrollMinSize should be equivalent to the scrollable area of the Panel.

Comment: `AutoScrollMinSize` reports (0,0) in my tests, but my answer works!!  ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, I know that the inverse works - assigning a Size to  AutoScrollMinSize changes the scrollable area of the control to that Size (assuming that the Size is larger than the ClientSize of the control).